# StartActivity in android broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I registered receiving SMS broadcast in manifest.xml.
How can I start new Activity in receive() method of the broadcast.
is there any flags of Intent to set or anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)   {

    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmDialog.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);    
}
```